# Operation Failed with "conda init powershell" (Windows 10)

Tags: python, powershell, virtualenv, conda, interpreter

I can't solve this problem with `conda init powershell`

I'm just trying to create a conda environment in my pycharm project to use Pytorch module.

This some information about my env status:

```
active environment : None
conda-build version : not installed
     python version : 3.9.7.final.0
   virtual packages : __cuda=11.0=0
                      __win=0=0
                      __archspec=1=x86_64
   base environment : C:\Users\GEB8D~1.GRI\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI220362  (read only)
  conda av data dir : C:\Users\GEB8D~1.GRI\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI220362\etc\conda
  conda av metadata url : None
       channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
      package cache : C:\Users\GEB8D~1.GRI\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI220362\pkgs
                      C:\Users\g.grillo\.conda\pkgs
                      C:\Users\g.grillo\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
   envs directories : C:\Users\g.grillo\.conda\envs
                      C:\Users\GEB8D~1.GRI\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI220362\envs
                      C:\Users\g.grillo\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
           platform : win-64
         user-agent : conda/4.10.3 requests/2.26.0 CPython/3.9.7 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.19044
      administrator : False
         netrc file : None
       offline mode : False
```

---

As You can see, none env is active because I can't init my powershell.
I tried also changing Terminal, or run in Admin mode but nothing change.
I've tried also all solution proposed in Leo questions and more, but nothing worked for me.

### This is the  Error

```
WARNING: Cannot install xonsh wrapper without a python interpreter in prefix: C:\Users\GEB8D~1.GRI\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI118522

needs sudo    C:\Users\GEB8D~1.GRI\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI118522\Scripts\conda.exe
needs sudo    C:\Users\GEB8D~1.GRI\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI118522\Scripts\conda-env.exe
modified      C:\Users\GEB8D~1.GRI\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI118522\Scripts\conda-script.py
modified      C:\Users\GEB8D~1.GRI\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI118522\Scripts\conda-env-script.py
needs sudo    C:\Users\GEB8D~1.GRI\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI118522\condabin\conda.bat
needs sudo    C:\Users\GEB8D~1.GRI\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI118522\Library\bin\conda.bat
needs sudo    C:\Users\GEB8D~1.GRI\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI118522\condabin\_conda_activate.bat
needs sudo    C:\Users\GEB8D~1.GRI\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI118522\condabin\rename_tmp.bat
needs sudo    C:\Users\GEB8D~1.GRI\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI118522\condabin\conda_auto_activate.bat
needs sudo    C:\Users\GEB8D~1.GRI\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI118522\condabin\conda_hook.bat
needs sudo    C:\Users\GEB8D~1.GRI\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI118522\Scripts\activate.bat
needs sudo    C:\Users\GEB8D~1.GRI\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI118522\condabin\activate.bat
needs sudo    C:\Users\GEB8D~1.GRI\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI118522\condabin\deactivate.bat
needs sudo    C:\Users\GEB8D~1.GRI\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI118522\Scripts\activate
needs sudo    C:\Users\GEB8D~1.GRI\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI118522\Scripts\deactivate
needs sudo    C:\Users\GEB8D~1.GRI\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI118522\etc\profile.d\conda.sh
needs sudo    C:\Users\GEB8D~1.GRI\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI118522\etc\fish\conf.d\conda.fish
needs sudo    C:\Users\GEB8D~1.GRI\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI118522\shell\condabin\Conda.psm1
needs sudo    C:\Users\GEB8D~1.GRI\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI118522\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1
needs sudo    C:\Users\GEB8D~1.GRI\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI118522\etc\profile.d\conda.csh
modified      C:\Users\g.grillo\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1
modified      HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun

==> For changes to take effect, close and re-open your current shell. <==

Operation failed.
```

I'm working in the env path, with windows 10.
Any advice will be appreciate, thanks!

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62434393/how-to-init-shell-for-conda-on-win-10 ?

Comment: It appears that you installed `conda` to `C:\Users\GEB8D~1.GRI\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI220362` is that correct and intended? I would advise to uninstall and then reinstall to a proper location first before taking more steps

Comment: Thanks both! I'll try and I'll update the question status asap.